Why doesn't my section highlight when it's in the viewport when all the others do?
I have a webpage with multiple sections denoted by the section HTML tag. The sections are supposed to highlight when they are in the viewport and their CSS class is set to the active state. All of the sections in my website highlight except for one. I want to know what the problem is and how to fix it.
I have included the relevant JS, CSS, and HTML code in the executable snippet below (it contains a way-oversimplified version of my site).


const [...sections] = document.getElementsByTagName('section');

/**
 * @function isVisible
 * @desc helper function to detect the element relative to the location in the viewport using .getBoundingClientRect()
 * @param {HTMLElement} section
 * @returns {boolean}
 */
    const isVisible = (section) => {
        const rect = section.getBoundingClientRect();
        return (
            rect.top >=0 &&
            rect.left>=0 &&
            rect.bottom <= (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight) &&
            rect.right <= (window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth)
        );

    }

/**
 * @function addCSSActiveState
 * @desc set CSS class active state when the element is in the viewport
 * @param sections
 */
    const addCSSActiveState = (sections) => {
        [...sections].forEach((section, index) => {
            if (isVisible(section)) {
                section.classList.add('active-section');
            }
            else {
                section.classList.remove('active-section');
            }
        })
    }


/**
 * @function
 * @listens window#scroll
 * @desc upon scrolling, setting the CSS class active state to the section in the viewport
 */
    window.addEventListener('scroll', (e) => {
        addCSSActiveState(sections);
    });
section.active-section {
  background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  background: linear-gradient(
          0deg,
          rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6) 0%,
          rgba(209, 198, 198, 0.185) 100%
  );
  backdrop-filter: blur(1px);
}

section.active-section .section-container::before {
  opacity: 1;
  animation: rotate 4s linear 0s infinite forwards;
}

section.active-section .section-container::after {
  opacity: 1;
  animation: rotate 5s linear 0s infinite forwards reverse;
}

@keyframes rotate {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg) translate(-1em) rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg) translate(-1em) rotate(-360deg);
  }
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no" />
        <title>Web Agency</title>
        <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.5.2/js/all.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
      <main>
       
        <section class="page-section" id="about">
            <div class="section-container">
                <div class="text-center">
                    <h2 class="section-heading text-uppercase">About</h2>
                </div>
                <ul class="timeline">
                    <li>
                        <div class="timeline-panel">
                            <div class="timeline-heading">
                                <h4>2001-2002</h4>
                                <h4 class="subheading">Our Cofounders Meet</h4>
                            </div>
                            <div class="timeline-body"><p class="text-muted">Our cofounders met at the University of California, Berkeley. . </p></div>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="timeline-inverted">
                        <div class="timeline-panel">
                            <div class="timeline-heading">
                                <h4>August 2006</h4>
                                <h4 class="subheading">Our First Product was Released</h4>
                            </div>
                            <div class="timeline-body"><p class="text-muted">Our first product, an ERP system was released.</p></div>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                       
                        <div class="timeline-panel">
                            <div class="timeline-heading">
                                <h4>May 2010</h4>
                                <h4 class="subheading">Our First Fortune 500 Client</h4>
                            </div>
                            <div class="timeline-body"><p class="text-muted">We landed our first Fortune 500 client.</p></div>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="timeline-inverted">
                       
                        <div class="timeline-panel">
                            <div class="timeline-heading">
                                <h4>September 2015</h4>
                                <h4 class="subheading">Expanding our Agency</h4>
                            </div>
                            <div class="timeline-body"><p class="text-muted">We greatly expanded the size of our headquarters office, staff, and regional offices.</p></div>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="timeline-inverted">
                        <div class="timeline-image">
                            <h4>
                                Get Involved
                                <br />
                                In Our
                                <br />
                                Journey!
                            </h4>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </section>
        <section class="page-section" id="team">
            <div class="section-container">
                <div class="text-center">
                    <h2 class="section-heading text-uppercase">Team</h2>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-4">
                        <div class="team-member">
                            <h4>Robert Holland, MBA</h4>
                            <p class="team-title">CEO</p>
                            <a class="btn btn-dark btn-social mx-2" href="https://x.com" aria-label="Robert Holland X Profile"><i class="fa-brands fa-x-twitter"></i></a>
                            <a class="btn btn-dark btn-social mx-2" href="https://facebook.com" aria-label="Robert Holland Facebook Profile"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></a>
                            <a class="btn btn-dark btn-social mx-2" href="https://linkedin.com" aria-label="Robert Holland LinkedIn Profile"><i class="fab fa-linkedin-in"></i></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-4">
                        <div class="team-member">
                            <h4>Monica Robles, PhD</h4>
                            <p class="team-title">CTO</p>
                            <a class="btn btn-dark btn-social mx-2" href="https://x.com" aria-label="Monica Robles X Profile"><i class="fa-brands fa-x-twitter"></i></a>
                            <a class="btn btn-dark btn-social mx-2" href="https://facebook.com" aria-label="Monica Robles Facebook Profile"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></a>
                            <a class="btn btn-dark btn-social mx-2" href="https://linkedin.com" aria-label="Monica Robles LinkedIn Profile"><i class="fab fa-linkedin-in"></i></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-4">
                        <div class="team-member">
                            <h4>James Chen, MS</h4>
                            <p class="team-title">CFO</p>
                            <a class="btn btn-dark btn-social mx-2" href="https://x.com" aria-label="James Chen X Profile"><i class="fa-brands fa-x-twitter"></i></a>
                            <a class="btn btn-dark btn-social mx-2" href="https://facebook.com" aria-label="James Chen Facebook Profile"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></a>
                            <a class="btn btn-dark btn-social mx-2" href="https://linkedin.com" aria-label="James Chen LinkedIn Profile"><i class="fab fa-linkedin-in"></i></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
      
            </div>
        </div>
        <section class="page-section" id="contact">
            <div class="section-container">
                <div class="text-center">
                    <h2 class="section-heading text-uppercase">Contact</h2>
                </div>
                <form id="contactForm">
                    <div class="row align-items-stretch mb-5">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input class="form-control" id="name" type="text" placeholder="Your Name *" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input class="form-control" id="email" type="email" placeholder="Your Email *" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group mb-md-0">
                                <input class="form-control" id="phone" type="tel" placeholder="Your Phone *"  />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="form-group form-group-textarea mb-md-0">
                                <textarea class="form-control" id="message" placeholder="Your Message *" ></textarea>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="text-center"><button class="btn btn-primary btn-xl text-uppercase" id="submitButton" type="submit">Send Message</button></div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </section>


      </main>
     
        <script src="js/app.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-cuYeSxntonz0PPNlHhBs68uyIAVpIIOZZ5JqeqvYYIcEL727kskC66kF92t6Xl2V" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </body>
</html>




what is sections?

a section in a document identified by a section html tag

Sorry, I was unclear. What is the variable sections

sorry i forgot to include the line  "const [...sections] = document.getElementsByTagName('section');" at the top

it's basically all the html section tags in the document

yes, I get that ... is that section added dynamically perhaps? document.getElementsByTagName returns a "live" list, but you convert it to an (static) Array - losing the benefit of a live list.  if you instead do const sections = document.getElementsByTagName('section'); and then [...sections].forEach((section, index) => { does that help?

all you have to add now is the isVisible function and you could create an executable snippet

just to let you know, this did in fact work. thanks!

So, are you saying that the section you showed above is added dynamically?

Also, you did have to change const [...sections] = document.getElementsByTagName('section'); to const sections = document.getElementsByTagName('section');

don't add answers inside your question. Either add an answer below or delete the question if you no more need it
